# Implementing custom system call in android kernel

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to implement a simple custom system call in the Nexus 4's kernel (mako). I have taken these five steps so far:

1. msm/arch/arm/kernel/calls.S

   ```
   ...
   /* 375 */   CALL(sys_setns)
   CALL(sys_process_vm_readv)
   CALL(sys_process_vm_writev)
   CALL(sys_hello)             /* a custom system call */
   ```
2. msm/include/linux/syscalls.h

   ```
   ...
   asmlinkage long sys_process_vm_writev(pid_t pid,
                 const struct iovec __user *lvec,
                 unsigned long liovcnt,
                 const struct iovec __user *rvec,
                 unsigned long riovcnt,
                 unsigned long flags);
   asmlinkage long sys_hello(void);
   ```
3. msm/arch/arm/include/asm/unistd.h

   ```
   ...
   #define __NR_setns                  (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+375)
   #define __NR_process_vm_readv       (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+376)
   #define __NR_process_vm_writev      (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+377)
   #define __NR_sys_hello              (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+378)
   ```
4. msm/Makefile

   ```
   ...
   # Objects we will link into vmlinux / subdirs we need to visit
   ...
   core-y      := usr/ hello/
   ```
5. msm/hello/sys_hello.c & msm/hello/Makefile

   ```
   #include <asm/unistd.d>
   #include <linux/linkage.h>

   asmlinkage long sys_hello(void) {
       printk("Hello world\n");
       return 0;
   }

   ##### BEGIN MAKEFILE #####
   obj-y := sys_hello.o
   ##### END MAKEFILE #####
   ```

I also used [this guide](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/general/howto-build-nexus-4-kernel-t2021202) to set up to build the kernel.

When I execute the `make mako_defconfig` and then  `make -j4` (this is from the guide), I am getting these errors:

```
arm-eabi-gcc -Wp,-MD,scripts/mod/.empty.o.d -nostdinc -isystem arm-eabi-gcc -print-file-name=include [Errno 13] Permission denied -I/Users/Edward/CMSI/android-kernel/kernel/msm/arch/arm/include -Iarch/arm/include/generated -Iinclude -include /Users/Edward/CMSI/android-kernel/kernel/msm/include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -Iarch/arm/mach-msm/include -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Os -fstack-protector -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -funwind-tables -D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=7 -march=armv5t -Wa,-march=armv7-a -msoft-float -Uarm -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DKBUILD_STR(s)=#s -DKBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(empty) -DKBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(empty) -c -o scripts/mod/empty.o scripts/mod/empty.c [Errno 13] Permission denied
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 13
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I am unable to determine if it's my fault in building the kernel, if I have missed a step so that the kernel identifies the new custom system call, or if there is a permission error with one of the files I modified.

Any suggestions would be helpful, this is my first time building a kernel for an Android device.

Edit: Now getting this error:

```
arm-eabi-gcc -Wp,-MD,kernel/.bounds.s.d -nostdinc -isystem arm-eabi-gcc -print-file-name=include [Errno 13] Permission denied -I/Users/Edward/CMSI/android-kernel/kernel/msm/arch/arm/include -Iarch/arm/include/generated -Iinclude -include /Users/Edward/CMSI/android-kernel/kernel/msm/include/linux/kconfig.h -D__KERNEL__ -mlittle-endian -Iarch/arm/mach-msm/include -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Os -fstack-protector -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -funwind-tables -D__LINUX_ARM_ARCH__=7 -march=armv5t -Wa,-march=armv7-a -msoft-float -Uarm -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DKBUILD_STR(s)=#s -DKBUILD_BASENAME=KBUILD_STR(bounds) -DKBUILD_MODNAME=KBUILD_STR(bounds) -fverbose-asm -S -o kernel/bounds.s kernel/bounds.c [Errno 13] Permission denied
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 13
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

Comment: You should always try to build the kernel *unmodified* and verify that it installs and runs before you change *anything*, so that you know if problems are due to the process or to your changes.  As for your specific error, a wild guess, but did you by any chance make an abortive attempt at building as root, and leave behind any files not owned by your account?  Otherwise your fastest resolution may be to get a new tree, diff your modified one and save any meaningful changes, then work forward with a test built in the new tree.

Comment: That's what I was thinking about doing. I will just save my changes and try building one scratch and see if I get any errors. Do you know if I'm setting up the custom system call correctly?

Comment: There's a "permission denied" error, do you have proper permission to do the build?

Comment: I'm quite interested to see how this turns out.